# Matplotlib plot with scalable/updatable x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to create a plot where a slider can update the length/location of the x-axis?

[Here](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=701966) is an example of the type of slider required.

A somewhat similar matplotlib slider can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html). Unfortunately, as you can see there is no documentation/explanation of how it works - this makes it rather difficult to understand/adapt!

The type of plot I would like to add this to is quite simple, here is a small, random example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

li = []
for x in xrange(100):
    li.append(random.randint(0,20))  

plt.plot(li)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. It's adapted directly from your second example in the matplotlib docs - using the slider to update the plot bounds, rather than to scale the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(5*np.pi*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s)

viewwindow = 0.1

axpos = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axslider = Slider(axpos, '', t[0]+viewwindow, t[-1]-viewwindow, valinit=(t[-1]+t[0])/2.0)

def update(val):
    new_pos = axslider.val
    ax.set_xbound(new_pos-viewwindow, new_pos+viewwindow)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

update(axslider.val)
axslider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you know how to set the value for the current view of the x-axis? It is currently set to 0.2 units and I can't see where this has been set (I assume it is default). But this is great, thank you!

Comment: In my example, the extents of the x-axis view are set by the `viewwindow` variable. When the slider position is changed, the `update` function is called, which sets the x bounds as the new postion +/- the value of `viewwindow`

Comment: By the way, matplotlib is extensively documented. You can read more about how the slider widget works [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider) and about axes functions like set_xbound [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xbound)